# Invalid coding system: auto-save-coding when trying to recover auto-save files

Tags: character-encoding, auto-save

Sometimes when I try to run `recover-this-file` I get an error `Invalid coding system: auto-save-coding` which prevents the file from being recovered. I had to manually find the autosave file and copy contents. Strangely it doesn't happen to all of my `recover-this-file` attempts and I'm not sure what's the cause of it. Also I could recover files with UTF-8 characters so I don't think non-ASCII characters are really the cause either.

Comment: Same here, I get this too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it has something to do with the plugin `wakatime`. Currently the workaround is to disable `global-wakatime-mode` when recovering a file and re-enable it afterwards. I've reported the [issue](https://github.com/wakatime/wakatime-mode/issues/10) but no reply yet.

Comment: I have this issue with `activity-watch-mode`.